# Obtener registros de varias tablas a partir de un solo query

Tags: php, mysql, refactoring

Obtener registros de varias tablas a partir de un solo query.

Tengo la siguiente estructura y datos, son 4 tablas:

***Tabla: Master_Producto***

```
Prod_Code   perfil  Marca   Orden   Catengoria
1           1       10      25      2
2           1       10      26      2
3           1       10      27      2
4           1       10      28      6
5           1       10      29      6
6           1       10      30      6
7           1       10      31      6
```

***Tabla: Producto_Estructura***

```
Prod_Code   perfil  UxC CxP
1           1       4   60
2           1       10  60
3           1       8   60
4           1       12  60
5           1       20  60
6           1       24  60
7           1       50  60
```

***Tabla: Producto_Proveedor***

```
Prod_Code   perfil  Proveedor
1           1       30
2           1       30
3           1       30
4           1       30
5           1       40
6           1       40
7           1       40
```

***Tabla: Producto_Precio***

```
Prod_Code   perfil  Price  Prod_DateUpd
1           1       10     20/10/2021
2           1       10     20/10/2021
1           1       5      19/10/2021
2           1       5      19/10/2021
3           1       20     20/10/2021
1           1       20     15/10/2021
1           1       15     15/10/2021
```

estas tablas tienen una relacion Manual por código de producto y perfil:
entonces el anterior programador desarrollo un scrip que ejcuta 4 querys individualmnte para extraer los datos:

```
$stmtpre1 = "SELECT * FROM Master_Producto WHERE Prod_Code='$Prod_Code' AND perfil=$Prod_FT;";
$stmtpre2 = "SELECT * FROM Producto_Estructura WHERE Prod_Code='$Prod_Code' AND perfil=$Prod_FT;";
$stmtpre3 = "SELECT * FROM Producto_Proveedor WHERE Prod_Code='$Prod_Code' AND perfil=$Prod_FT;";
$stmtpre4 = "SELECT * FROM Producto_Precio WHERE Prod_Code='$Prod_Code' AND perfil=$Prod_FT;";
```

Luego ejecuta las consultas las asocia y devuelve un solo array:

```
$result = [];
$data1                  = $this->BDquery($stmtpre1, DB_PRODUCT);
$result['Prod_Profile'] = $this->BDasociar($data1);
$data2                  = $this->BDquery($stmtpre2, DB_PRODUCT);
$result['Prod_Info']    = $this->BDasociar($data2);
$data3                  = $this->BDquery($stmtpre3, DB_PRODUCT);
$result['Prod_Prov']    = $this->BDasociar($data3);
$data4                  = $this->BDquery($stmtpre4, DB_PRODUCT);
$result['Prod_Precio']  = $this->BDasociar($data4);

return $result;
```

he llegado a la conclusión de que esta implementación no es eficiente, y que las múltiples conexiones y análisis en consultas cuando se manejen mas de 2000 producto sancionara drásticamente el tiempo de ejecución, he pensado en replantear el script y refactorizarlo, pero desconozco como implementar la UNION de tablas.

alquilen me colabora con la refactorización del Query, lo ideal seria ejecutar uno solamente.

```
$stmtpre = implode(" UNION ", [$stmtpre1,$stmtpre2,$stmtpre2,$stmtpre2]);
```

pero no me funciona.

**UPDATE #1**

***Ejemplo:***

```
(SELECT * FROM Master_Producto WHERE Prod_Code='1' AND perfil=1) UNION (SELECT * FROM Producto_Estructura WHERE Prod_Code='1' AND perfil=1) UNION (SELECT * FROM Producto_Proveedor WHERE Prod_Code='1' AND perfil=1) UNION (SELECT * FROM Producto_Precio WHERE Prod_Code='1' AND perfil=1)
```

Error:

> El comando SELECT usado tiene diferente número de columnas

**UPDATE #2**
***Otro Intento usando Righ Join:***
**nota:** se contempla traer solo el ultimo registro de `Producto_Precio`

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Master_Producto
RIGHT JOIN(
        Producto_Estructura
    ON
        Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Estructura.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Estructura.Prod_PF
    )
RIGHT JOIN(
        Producto_Proveedor
    ON
        Producto_Estructura.Prod_Code = Producto_Proveedor.Prod_Code AND Producto_Estructura.Prod_PF = Producto_Proveedor.Prod_PF
    )
RIGHT JOIN(
        Producto_Precio
    ON
        Producto_Estructura.Prod_Code = Producto_Precio.Prod_Code AND Producto_Estructura.Prod_PF = Producto_Precio.Prod_PF
    ORDER BY
        Prod_DateUpd
    DESC
LIMIT 1
    )
```

Error:

> Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'ON

***¿Hay Otra Alternativa?: sii.***

Comment: Te recomiendo usar mejor LEFT JOIN, ya me paso algo parecido anteriormente, y por alguna razón el RIGHT JOIN no se funcionaba como quería.

Comment: @JosueVargas si, ya lo hice y prácticamente eh resuelto este problema y estoy a un 75%, perooo tengo otros dos problemas ahora , ***primero:*** las tablas que vez en el post son de ejemplo, la realidad es que son casi 10 tablas, y algunas de estas tienen hasta 20 columnas con nombres repetidos XD, ***segundo*** algunos datos son insertados por fecha por lo que para un Producto y perfil pueden haber 3 o mas fechas y en teoría debo traer la ultima solamente del left join ...

Comment: Ya lo que comentas son más detalles, lo que te recomiendo es, primero, hacer un query con LEFT JOIN y usar alias en cada campo (LOSE, es la locura), segundo, ya con el query en PHP ya validas la "última fecha" y otro detalle, pero lo importante es que traigas todo en una consulta.

Comment: @JosueVargas ya construi el query y funciona perfecto en phpmyadmin pero no jala ni datos ni error en la web...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo ideal es implementar `LEFT JOIN` como lo comento el compañero @JosueVargas;
y tambien utilizar SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM Master_Producto
LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM Producto_Estructura) AS Producto_Estructura ON ( Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Estructura.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Estructura.Prod_PF)
LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM Producto_Proveedor) AS Producto_Proveedor ON ( Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Proveedor.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Proveedor.Prod_PF)
LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM Producto_Precio ORDER BY Prod_DateUpd DESC) AS Producto_Precio ON ( Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Precio.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Precio.Prod_PF)
```

Probado con el `phpmyadmin` funciona correctamente, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar desde el `php`. eso es tema para otro post: [script php no devuelve nada pero phpmyadmin si](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/487998/46896)