# script php no devuelve nada pero phpmyadmin si

Tags: php, mysql

Partiendo de la siguiente estructura de ejemplo hipotética:

***Tabla: Master_Producto***

```
Prod_Code   perfil  Marca   Orden   Categoría
1           1       10      25      2
2           1       10      26      2
3           1       10      27      2
4           1       10      28      6
5           1       10      29      6
6           1       10      30      6
7           1       10      31      6
```

***Tabla: Producto_Estructura***

```
Prod_Code   perfil  UxC CxP
1           1       4   60
2           1       10  60
3           1       8   60
4           1       12  60
5           1       20  60
6           1       24  60
7           1       50  60
```

***Tabla: Producto_Proveedor***

```
Prod_Code   perfil  Proveedor
1           1       30
2           1       30
3           1       30
4           1       30
5           1       40
6           1       40
7           1       40
```

***Tabla: Producto_Precio***

```
Prod_Code   perfil  Price  Prod_DateUpd
1           1       10     20/10/2021
2           1       10     20/10/2021
1           1       5      19/10/2021
2           1       5      19/10/2021
3           1       20     20/10/2021
1           1       20     15/10/2021
1           1       15     15/10/2021
```

implemente la siguiente consulta para traer todos los datos:

```
SELECT * FROM Master_Producto
LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM Producto_Estructura) AS Producto_Estructura ON ( Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Estructura.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Estructura.Prod_PF)
LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM Producto_Proveedor) AS Producto_Proveedor ON ( Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Proveedor.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Proveedor.Prod_PF)
LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM Producto_Precio ORDER BY Prod_DateUpd DESC) AS Producto_Precio ON ( Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Precio.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Precio.Prod_PF)
```

Probado con el `phpmyadmin` funciona correctamente, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar desde el `php`.

sucede que esto se ejecuta mediante `ajax` y el `response` y `error` son devueltos vacíos; cuando se espera que venga siempre algo ojala sea basura...

el escenario como las comentaba es hipotético, digamos que la consulta real usa el mismo patrón, a 10 tablas donde hay entre 2000 productos en el maestro y en las otras tablas puede haber entre 2000 a 500,000 registros. vuelvo y repito en `phpmyadmin` se ejecuta correctamente el `Query`.

*hay como 500 columnas ...*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Estos son los script:

***donde todo inicia:***

```php
<?php
    $stmtpre           = "SELECT * FROM Master_Producto
    LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM Producto_Estructura) AS Producto_Estructura ON ( Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Estructura.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Estructura.Prod_PF)
    LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM Producto_Proveedor) AS Producto_Proveedor ON ( Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Proveedor.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Proveedor.Prod_PF)
    LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM Producto_Precio ORDER BY Prod_DateUpd DESC) AS Producto_Precio ON ( Master_Producto.Prod_Code = Producto_Precio.Prod_Code AND Master_Producto.Prod_PF = Producto_Precio.Prod_PF);";
    $data              = $this->BDquery($stmtpre, DB_PRODUCT); //aquí se queda
    //nada despues de este punto se ejecuta;
    echo '<pre>';
    echo var_export($data,true);
    echo '</pre>';
```

***y los script de conexión a la base de datos:***
**Nota:** este script solo se usa para buscar datos que no requieren parámetros de búsqueda.

```php
<?php

    function Open_Con_DB($dbUsing) {
            $error            = [];
            $error['dberror'] = 'no';
            $dblink           = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASS); # verificar donde se incluye el puerto
            $selected         = mysqli_select_db($dblink, DB_PRE . $dbUsing); # verificar donde se incluye el puerto
            if (!$selected) {$error = $this->errorDB($dblink);} # Verificacion de Errores de Coneccion a la base de Datos
            try {
                if ($error['dberror'] == true) {
                    throw new Exception('A ocurrido un Error De coneccion a la Base de Datos.<br>' . $error['msg']);
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br>Error Trasado:' . $e->getTraceAsString();
                die('Proceso Cancelado');
            }
            $dblink->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); # Enlace de Coneccion UTF-8
            return $dblink;
    }
    
    function Close_Con_DB($dblink) {
        mysqli_close($dblink);
    }
    
    function ErrorDB($dblink) {
        $error['msg']     = 'Indicacion: ' . mysqli_error($dblink);
        $error['dberror'] = true;
        return $error;
    }

    function BDquery($dbquery, $dbUsing) {
        $dblink = $this->Open_Con_DB($dbUsing);
        $datos  = mysqli_query($dblink, $dbquery) or $this->errorDB($dblink);
        $this->Close_Con_DB($dblink);
        return $datos;
    }
```

---

**Configuracion del MySQL:**

```
[client]
#password=your_password
port=3306
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port=3306
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size=512M
max_allowed_packet=2048M
table_open_cache=256
sort_buffer_size=8M
read_buffer_size=8M
read_rnd_buffer_size=16M
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
thread_cache_size=8

secure-file-priv=""
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=1
datadir= "C:/laragon/data/mysql"
lower_case_table_names=2
sql_mode=""


[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=2048M
```

---

**Update #1:**
Se me había olvidado revisar el Log de MySQL, aquí están los datos:

```
2021-10-01T22:12:10.757688Z 120 [Note] Aborted connection 120 to db: 'dbproducts' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error writing communication packets)
```

**Update #2:**
me ha dado por revisar el log de apache:

```
[Fri Oct 01 19:29:28.308182 2021] [cgi:error] [pid 12144:tid 1124] [client 127.0.0.1:58769] AH01215: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24576 bytes) in Unknown on line 0: C:/laragon/bin/php/php72/php-cgi.exe, referer: http://avi2.me/
```

para tan pocos byte:

Configuración:

el servidor web corre sobre `php 7.2` como en la siguiente imagenes, pero el phpmyadmin se ejecuta con `php 7.4`  apache handres 2.0, los dos ambientes tienen las mismas variables de entorno 3gb de limite de memoria.

PHPMyAdmin ejecuta todo correctamente y la app web no

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Variables del Entorno, será que 1 GB es muy poco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

***Dudas:*** 
**si el problema es de memoria se va a mas de 3GB pero sigo sin entender por que en php-cgi se muere para y no en phpmyadmin?

¿si la conexión fue abortada por que no obtengo un error?

¿entonces no se donde puede estar el error o que debo corregir?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código está mal concebido y quizá el motivo del *aborted connection* sea ese error en la concepción de tu código (aunque la causa puede ser otra, como problemas de cortaguegos y demás).

Si nos fijamos en tu método `BDquery()`, ahí estarías obteniendo un recurso con `mysqli_query()`, luego cierras la conexión y retornas el recurso. OK, muy bonito, pero hacer eso es ignorar cómo funciona mysqli. Cuando necesites leer el recurso `$datos` **la conexión estará cerrada y tú necesitas la conexión para leer el recurso** y ese podría ser el motivo del error.

Una forma de resolver esto sería leer los datos dentro del método y retornarlos leídos, no como un recurso:

```
function BDquery($dbquery, $dbUsing) {
    $dblink = $this->Open_Con_DB($dbUsing);
    if ($dblink) {
        if ( $datos = mysqli_query($dblink, $dbquery) ) {
            $outPut=array();
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)) {
                $outPut[]=$row;
            }
        } else {
            $outPut['error']=$this->errorDB($dblink);
        }
        $this->Close_Con_DB($dblink);
    } else {
        $outPut['error']='No hay conexión';
    }
    return $outPut;
}
```

Aquí `$outPut` será, o los datos ya leídos o los posibles errores que hayan ocurrido. Y si hay problema de no conexión también lo sabrás, dado que se hace una comprobación de la misma.

---

Por otra parte, tu método `Open_Con_DB()` es estrambótico. Puedes simplificarlo así:

```
function Open_Con_DB($dbUsing) {
    $dblink = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASS, DB_PRE . $dbUsing);
    if ($dblink) {
        $dblink->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); # Enlace de Coneccion UTF-8
        return $dblink;
    } else {
        #No conviene mostrar errores internos
        #Cámbialos por mensajes personalizados en producción
        die( 'Error de Conexión ('
             .mysqli_connect_errno(). ') '
             . mysqli_connect_error()
            );
        return null;
    }
}
```

Como podrás ver, hemos pasado la base de datos en la misma llamada a la función, porque mysqli permite esto (a diferencia de la anciana mysql_ que no lo permitía).

No hay ninguna necesidad con liarse con bloques `try ... catch`. Simplemente nos preocupamos porque la conexión sea válida y si no lo es lanzamos un mensaje de error. De todos modos, si por algún motivo te interesa trabajar con Excepciones, puedes levantar una en la parte del `else`  (donde está el `die()`)

Comment: muchas gracias estera evaluando tu respuesta

Comment: mira s bastante raro por que nunca ha tenido problema con cerrar la conexión y retornar el recurso hay alguna documentación en la que cerrar la conexión destruya los recursos???

Comment: implemente todo o que me comentaste y el error persiste. asumo que no es ninguno de los dos script, ya que consultas mas peques las ejecutan sin problemas.

Comment: encontré otro indicio lo agregue a mi post.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso ¿Habiendo modificado los métodos `BDquery()`  y `Open_Con_DB()` como te he sugerido persiste el mismo problema o el error es otro? Yo creo que si la conexión es abortada en este contexto la misma debería ser nula y la versión del código que te sugiero es capaz de detectar una conexión nula. Ahora bien, si la conexión aborta en la lectura de los datos (en `BDquery()`) entonces habría que buscar otros motivos, como podrían ser: firewall, limitaciones de memoria, incompatibilidades, etc. Yo probaría con una consulta que arroje pocos datos para ver si es eso.

Comment: definitivamente es problema de gestión de memoria, pasa con fastCGI y no con apache handler 2.0 mira el post me lo lleve a server fault por si estas interesado en seguirlo: https://serverfault.com/questions/1079354/web-page-shows-me-timeout-gateway-error-fastcgi

Comment: no acepto que algo funcione en apache y en fastCGI no

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso creo que en ServerFault te están diciendo algo parecido a lo que te sugerí: probar una consulta que arroje pocos datos. Si funciona entonces el problema sería otro. Sea como sea, casi nunca se requiere un resultado con varios cientos de miles de filas, en esos casos debería pensarse en traer los resultados paginados y/o verificar los índices de las tablas y demás. En cualquiera de los casos, esto no tendría que ver con PHP sino con el diseño de la base de datos y la lógica a implementar (paginación por ejemplo en vez de todos los resultados de golpe).